# Output rating on charger/transformer says "AC". Is this actually AC output?

Tags: charger

I've searched here but can't find a specific answer. I have a charger/transformer for a cordless device that is rated as: "Input: AC 120v  60Hz 50mA" "Output: 3v AC 100mA" 
My question is...on such units, do they ACTUALLY put out voltage in AC? Would a charger unit rated as Output 3v DC do the same thing or are they completely different? It is difficult to find one that has output voltage rating as AC.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they do. They're pretty much just a transformer, with some measure of overvoltage protection on the more expensive ones.

Comment: In addition to over-voltage protection, these wall wart transformers are also usually short-circuit safe.  That means you can short their outputs and it won't catch fire.

Answer (score 1):

Is it heavy? Then yes. Is it very light? Then probably not. Stick a multimeter into the output and measure it!

Comment: It is a small unit to recharge a cordless Waterpik. I'm at work  and was just doing searches for an answer. I'll check it with a meter when I get home. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a cordless WaterPik, and its charger does indeed produce 3 volts AC, just like the label says.

Answer (score 0):

Yes products actually need this reasons for this might be:
1) They need 60Hz for a clock to keep time because they are too cheap to buy an RTC
2) It may be cheaper to buy AC transformers and have only one LDO in your product.